# Reading an app setting value from iOS Settings-MyApp using Ionic

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ipad, ionic5

I want to create a app specific setting(app preference) in iOS(iPad) and read that in my Ionic(v5) code. I have seen plugins like https://github.com/chrisekelley/AppPreferences/ this but not working with the cordova-9 as it was not updated. Looks like this project is abandoned.I was able to create a setting bundle during the build and place it under the settings->Myapp (key-value) but from the program reading is not working.

My requirement is very simple. I need to externalize the back-end server IP/name as it might change sometimes. I was thinking if I can create a property under Settings->MyApp->Server then I can edit it in the Settings and read it while starting the app.

Is there a different approach that I can follow?

Please let me know if you have any pointers.